# Serializing object using messagepack and as3

Tags: actionscript-3, serialization, msgpack, messagepack

This is a vary simple question, but can't find any docs on it.

I have a simple class:

```
public class User
{
    public var name:String;
    public var age:int;
}
```

I would like to serialize it using this:

```
var user:User = new User();
user.age = 15;
user.name = "mike";
//now serialize
var bytes:ByteArray = MessagePack.encoder.write(vo);
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: MessagePack handler for type base not found
```

How do I let MessagePack know what the User class is, how to serialize it?

Comment: Which version of MessagePack do you use ? Where can I find it ?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/loteixeira/as3-msgpack, it's the latest version, I think v0.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessagePack doesn't look like being able to serialize Class, like most serializer.

I suggest you to add a `toObject` method to your User class :

```
public function toObject():Object
{
    return {age:this.age, name:this.name}:
}
```

Then you can serialize your user :

```
var bytes:ByteArray = MessagePack.encoder.write(user.toObject());
```

You can also add a static `fromObject` method which takes an object and returns a new User initialized with this object.

```
static public function fromObject(o:Object):User
{
    var u = new User();
    u.age = o.age;
    u.name = o.name;

    return u;
}
```